# NFT not being created on Goerli network

Tags: nft, hardhat

I am trying to launch an nft using this 3 part tutorial: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-write-and-deploy-an-nft/

I followed everything up to the 3rd part of the course, but the etherscan page isn't showing a TokenID nor a contractID when I go there: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x1a04a57c82e8624a049be299e27ab4585c4f4d22ae99dbdefe7e649b73473f14

Here is my mint-nft code:

```
require("dotenv").config()
const API_URL = process.env.API_URL
const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.PUBLIC_KEY
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3")
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(API_URL)

const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/MyNFT.sol/MyNFT.json")
const contractAddress = "0x81c587EB0fE773404c42c1d2666b5f557C470eED"
const nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)

async function mintNFT(tokenURI) {
  const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY, "latest") //get latest nonce

  //the transaction
  const tx = {
    from: PUBLIC_KEY,
    to: contractAddress,
    nonce: nonce,
    gas: 500000,
    data: nftContract.methods.mintNFT(PUBLIC_KEY, tokenURI).encodeABI(),
  }

  const signPromise = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY)
  signPromise
    .then((signedTx) => {
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        signedTx.rawTransaction,
        function (err, hash) {
          if (!err) {
            console.log(
              "The hash of your transaction is: ",
              hash,
              "\nCheck Alchemy's Mempool to view the status of your transaction!"
            )
          } else {
            console.log(
              "Something went wrong when submitting your transaction:",
              err
            )
          }
        }
      )
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Promise failed:", err)
    })
}

mintNFT("ipfs://QmQgvyZRVBQeDHBP6zLPvvjDy6f9QBSCkrrzSF7H8K7wgx")
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked the contract address you are using on Goerli const `contractAddress = "0x81c587EB0fE773404c42c1d2666b5f557C470eED"` and it doesn't look like a contract, is a EOA.

Checking the tx of the above wallet. probably the contract address you need is this one: `0x3A632C370dFE7d32F74Da5A84b7e72571bD6Da7C`, but I haven't test it.

Hope it helps and welcome to the community!